# Storing tags value for displaying content

Tags: php, mysql

I have **150+** tags (more in future), **18000+** of different content to display and **380+** users (more in future).

What will be the best way to display content to users according to the **Tag** value for the user?

I thought of storing all tag activities in the database like:

```
 ________________________________
| Sr. | User_Id | Tag_Id | Int.  |
|________________________________|
| 1   | 152     | 18     | 15    |
| 2   | 152     | 24     | 8     |
| 3   | 18      | 127    | 4     |
|________________________________|
```

In database `Int.` means how many times the user is interested in the posts having `Tag_Id`.

As the user clicks <kbd>Interested?</kbd> the `Int.` column will be `+1` for that user and that tag.

If I store the values in the database, the database will have huge content and huge **traffic** and will **need large storage** too. (**108K** values only for now then imagine the stage of values after 2 years.)

**Any other best alternatives?**

I am using PHP & MySQL.

Comment: You should just be able to use `count()` and `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

For the best RM model solution, you will have to give some more information about the complete model. But as I see it now, this is the best solution. You can remove the id and set the primary key to `user_id` and `tag_id` (both).

Comment: Updated the question. (in & after database table)

Comment: I think this is the best option... you can also use a NoSQL database like MongoDB... which is much faster and you don't have to worry about PK and FK

Comment: `remove the id`, do you mean the `Sr.` column?

Comment: Yes... it's not needed if you place the primary key on user_id and tag_id. I don't know if you were going to do it, but you'll need to place a foreign key on user_id and tag_id.